# Get values for last three week of data for the same day same timestamp

Tags: postgresql

I have a query where I would like to get the values of specific columns for last three weeks for same timestamp and same day.

```
with rc_pt as (
               SELECT
                    DISTINCT timestamp AS timestamp,           
                    rc_id AS rc_id,
                    pt_id AS pt_id,
                    impacted_users AS impacted_users_prev_day
                    from pt_rc
                    where timestamp between '2022-10-28 11:00:00' ::timestamp-'1 day 1 hour'::interval
                    and '2022-10-28 11:00:00'::timestamp-'23 hours'::interval
                       
                                            
           )
select * from rc_pt
```

This is my current query which is trying to get data from last day's data.
I tried `date_part()` but it looks unclear how can I get the data from last three weeks for the same day and timestamp.

Comment: Note that `timestamp AS timestamp` can be simplified to `timestamp`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the question you need to have the same day and time 1, 2 and 3 weeks back from a certain timestamp. If so then this illustration may help.

```sql
with t(ts) as (select '2022-12-01 10:30:01'::timestamp)
select
  ts "the timestamp",
  ts::date -  7 + ts::time "a week ago", 
  ts::date - 14 + ts::time "2 weeks ago", 
  ts::date - 21 + ts::time "3 weeks ago"
from t;
```

| the timestamp | a week ago | 2 weeks ago | 3 weeks ago |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-01 10:30:01.000 | 2022-11-24 10:30:01.000 | 2022-11-17 10:30:01.000 | 2022-11-10 10:30:01.000 |

Comment: somehow this did not work for me. would it be possible to write with the same columns I have mentioned?